# CSS setting flex-wrap after overflowing content

Tags: css

Is it possible to make `flex-wrap` wrap after the last row overflows **without** vertical scroll like it is possible horizontally?

My CSS currently looks like this:

```
.flex-container {
  height: calc(100% - 0.125rem);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  width: 6.25rem;
  height: 6.25rem;
  margin: 1px 0 0 1px;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 6.25rem;
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
```

My output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ8DI.png) (flex wraps and empty space below)

What I am trying to achieve looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paYVI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, I think the challenge you have is with the **height** property of the **.flex-container** class.

`height: calc(100% - 0.125rem)` will leave an offset(gap) since the height of `.item` `6.25rem > 0.125rem`.

For the height of `.flex-container` try `height: calc(100% - 6.25rem)` instead, or tweak the **height** property until you get your desired output.

Note that the **flex-wrap** property only specifies if the flex items should stay on one line or can wrap onto multiple lines, which you already have specified. And with the **overflow** property set to hidden, you should not have any challenges with scrolls.

Comment: Yes! This was the fix for my issue. Changing the height as `height: 44.25rem` which is for 7 rows and 1px border for each was the very easy fix that I overlooked. Thank you!